# Match all specified words within a tag

Tags: regex, vba, vbscript

I want to match following pattern: match all uppercase letter-only words in brackets and inside `<b></b>` tags.

**Example:**

```
(ABC) 'must extract none
<b>(ABC) 'must extract none
<b>(ABC)(CDE)(EFG)</b> 'must extract ABC, CDE and EFG
<b> shr (ABC) апаd (CDE)   lgsgs   </b> 'must extract ABC and CDE
<b>A</b>(ABCA)<b>(ABCB)</b> 'must extract only ABCB
<b>A</b>(ABCA)<b>dada(ABCB)wsg</b> 'must extract only ABCB
<b>AB</b>(ABCA)<b>BC</b>(ABCB) 'must extract none
```

I tried to use following pattern, but it matches only first occurrence:

```
"(<b>(?:(?!<\/?b>).)*?\()([A-Z]+)(\)(?:(?!<\/?b>).)*<\/b>)"
```

Comment: Try to test/build your regex at http://regex101.com/, there are plenty of pre-defined patterns in their library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex.

```
(?:[A-Z]+(?=\)))(?=(?:(?!<\/?b>).)*<\/b>)
```

- `(?:[A-Z]+(?=\)))` It would match one or more uppercase letters only if it's followed by a closing `)` bracket.
- `(?=(?:(?!<\/?b>).)*<\/b>)` And aslo it must be followed by any character but not of opening or closing `<b>` tag zero or more times and then it must be followed by a closing `</b>` tag.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zW3lE9/1)

OR

Simply like this,

```
(?:[A-Z]+(?=\)))(?=[^<>]*<\/b>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zW3lE9/2)